# Why is our only migration option to "Migrate to meta"?

Tags: discussion, migration

I thought that we were allowed 3-5 targets for migration.

[This user](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57842/what-to-do-about-references-in-an-interview-based-report)'s been asking a series of questions that aren't in any way about the English language and should probably be on Academia but I can't even recommend that in the migrate page:

[image: Migrate option]

Am I just failing to understand how this works?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's because we're still in beta. I usually flag those for moderator attention and just explain where I think they should migrate to.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  That seems to be the case. I did some digging on Meta (the big meta and it seems that they don't... so I asked [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257317/can-beta-sites-slated-for-graduation-get-full-site-abilities-without-site-design) question.

Comment: This works the other way too: over on EL&U, we have no standard option to migrate to ELL :/

Comment: I was bothered by this, and asked a duplicate question. I have been selecting 'other' as my reason, and writing which other SE site I think it belongs on.

Comment: Canned migration paths seem to have an extremely high bar for being set up; they're generally actively avoided unless there's a relatively high volume of quite accurate migrations. In other words, unless we need it badly and migrations to that site are almost always right, it's not going to happen.

Comment: Are you sure you need to name and shame? But, yes, I agree - we need more migration options! (And especially one for ELL on ELU.)

Comment: @DogLover An important part of meta is showing examples of the issue. It's not about calling another user out, it's about letting people see what you're talking about.